# Outlook flashes / flickers after clikcing Open Task button from a SharePoint workflow email notification

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-outlook, workflow

I have developed a custom workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010. The workflow runs as expected. I receive the email notification that a task has been assigned to me and the email asks me to click the Open this task button. When I click that button, Outlook starts flashing / flickering. I have to either press Escape or end the Outlook process to get the flickering to stop. I am able to reproduce this exact scenario on multiple computers (Windows 7 Office 2010). I tried the same process through OWA and the button works fine. I have read to edit the formserver.aspx in the 14 bin on the SharePoint server, but that file does not exist in my environment. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for a solution for a while. I tried this:

1. click Start–>Run–> Type `Regedit` and hit enter
2. Regeditor comes up
3. Then navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ActiveX  Compatibility\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`
4. Delete the key (looks like a folder) that is named `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`
5. Then restart Outlook

but I did not find the `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` folder. I have a 64-bit pc, so instead i tried this:

1. Click Start->Run->Type `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedt32.exe`
2. Then navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ActiveX Compatibility\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`
3. Delete the key (looks like a folder) that is named `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`
4. Then restart Outlook

   This worked for me. Finally the Open this task button works in Outlook!!!!